# how to read data from a web browser

Tags: winforms

i need to read data from a web browser and add some of this data to my database.
data is in web browser table.

Answer (score 2):

You can manipulate the DOM of a document loaded inside [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control by obtaining a reference to an [HtmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx):

```
if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    // find the table by id
    HtmlElement table = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id_of_the_table");
    // use the table to extract data from columns and rows
    foreach (HtmlElement rowElem in table.GetElementsByTagName("TR"))
    {
        string html = rowElem.InnerHtml;
        // ...
    }
}
```